# replace space or encode it

Tags: jquery

I have following Jquery call.

```
$("#btnfindAddress").click(function() {
   var dataString = '';
        //built the data string that will be sent with ajax
        dataString += 'business_name='+$('#company').val()+'&';
        dataString += 'business_city='+$('#city').val()+'&';
        dataString += 'business_country='+$('#country').val()+'&';
        dataString += 'business_zipcode='+$('#zipcode').val();
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/locations/search",
contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
data: dataString, 
success: function(data){ 
    var text_result="";
    text_result="<table  id=\"thetable\"><tbody>";
    $.each(data,function(index,value){
          text_result+="<tr>";
          text_result+="<td>"+value.name+"</td>";
          text_result+="<td>"+value.address+"</td>";
          text_result+="<td>"+value.zipcode+"</td>";
          text_result+="<td><a name="+ value.name+" address="+value.address+" city="+value.city+"href=>Select</a></td>";
          text_result+="</tr>";
    });
          $('#locations').html(text_result);
}
});
 return false; 
});
```

it generates the following html

```
<a href="" angeles="" city="Los" website="null" zipcode="90007"  st="" hoover="" s="" address="3303" coffee="" name="Starbucks">Select</a>
```

The values are splited by space.

It should have been

```
    <a href="" city="Los angeles"   address="3303 S Hoover st" coffee="" name="Starbucks">Select</a>
```

How can i fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be building the `data` component by hand.  Just use an object literal: `$.ajax({ ..., data: {foo: 'bar', business_city: $("#city").val()}});`

Comment: `it generates the following html` No it doesn't. That's what your DOM explorer is telling you. Not the actual HTML. Do a _View Source_ and you'll see what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add quotes to generated html:

```
text_result+="<td><a name=\""+ value.name+"\" address=\""+value.address+"\" city=\""+value.city+"\" href>Select</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be doing this with string manipulation. jQuery handles the encoding properly if you do the following...

```
var $table = $('<table>').attr('id','theTable');
$.each(data,function(index,value) {
    $table.append(
       $('<tr>')
         .append($('<td>').text(value.name))
         .append($('<td>').text(value.address))
         .append($('<td>').text(value.zipcode))
         .append($('<td>').append(
           $('<a>').attr('name',value.name).attr('address',value.address)
         )
    );
});
$('#locations').html($('<div>').append($table).html());
```

Even better would be to use a templating approach like EJS or Moustache.

Comment: i like this approach better. its clean. But for some reason the $table.append not working .. may be missing something ..

Comment: I'm not privy to the data coming back in the AJAX. This approach is very basic and used quite frequently but even better to use a JavaScript templating engine. I encourage considering that as it will save quite a of time and give an even cleaner approach. EJS is my favorite as a personal preference.